# How to copy and paste the files from shared folder or from another server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am creating application. In that, I put combo box, combo box filled by application no. came from db. on the selection of combo box the grid fill that files which in another machine in drive. Like `//user/public/af001/edit/test.JPEG` and in grid I put the download link on particular row for download that file in my machine but issue is when I am downloading that file, I am not geting `//user/public/af001/edit/test.JPEG`.

```
            if (e.Column Index == 0)
            {
                int row;
                //Get the row index
                row = e.Row Index;

                string old Path = @"~\\Users\Public\AS\AFS1402190001\Edit\test.JPEG";
                string new path = @"E:\example\";
                string new File Name = "new file name";
                File Info f1 = new File Info(old Path);
                if (f1.Exists)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(new path))
                    {
                        Directory.Create Directory(new path);
                    }
                    f1.Copy To(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", new path, new File Name, f1.Extension));
                }
             }
```

Can you tell me what is the issue?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is it not downloading, there must be some exception. Paste that, also do you have rights and permission(account) to access files, or are you using ASP.Net account, which is by default?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
   string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", new path, new File Name, f1.Extension);
```

it looks you are not building a correct file patch. try to use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to combine directory and fileName. something like:

```
System.IO.Path.Combine(dirPath, string.Format("{0}.{1}", fileName, extension));
```

of course, you might want to make sure the path/filename does not have invalid chars, you can use `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()` and `System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()` to get those illegal chars that you need to avoid.

Comment: thanks but old path, that is in another PC from that PC i copy the files and paste in my machine, how can i do ?

Comment: So this piece of code is running in your machine, right? if so, then you have to make the other PC share the folder out and use network folder to locate the file, the ultimate location for the old file should be \\oldMachineNameOrIP\SharedFolderName\fileName

Comment: to test it before you start to code, you should be able to browse the network folder (shared from your old box).

Comment: i think i did not look at your question properly - did you use this for a website? or Winform/WCF application? if it's a website, it would be a different story...

Comment: yes this code is in my machine, and i want to copy and paste file / image from the other machine. i am working on desktop application, so i am able to find the path of other machine. how can i find?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47910/discussion-between-rex-and-ranjita-das) - not able to chat due to proxy

Comment: quickest is to type "\\yourOldMachineNameOrIpAddress" in any open window's address bar and hit enter

Comment: \\JAIMINI\Users\Public\AFS\AFS1402190001\Edit this is the path from edit folder, i will download the image.when i write in code, error came could not fine.

Comment: are you sure the variable oldpath has the same value as "\\JAIMINI\Users\Public\AFS\AFS1402190001\Edit\test.JPEG"? can you put a breakpoint in your code and check it out?

Comment: yes, from this path i get all the image and fill in grid also but when i click on download button and set static path then also error came that could not find.old path is : string oldPath = @"\\JAIMINI\Users\Public\AFS\AFS1402190001\Edit\desert.jpeg";

Comment: string oldPath = @"\\JAIMINI\Users\Public\AFS\AFS1402190001\Edit\Desert.jpeg";
                    string newpath = @"E:\example\";
                    string newFileName = "new file name";
                    FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo(oldPath);
                    if (f1.Exists).....in this f1.exists is false

Comment: can you try a command at your command line, see whether you can finish this command (you can choose another test folder you like): copy "\\JAIMINI\Users\Public\AFS\AFS1402190001\Edit\Desert.jpeg" /D "C:\temp\Desert.jpeg"

Comment: then also it not able to find the old path. :(

Comment: that's the problem - you are not able to browse the old machine from your new machine, mostlikely you did not share the folder over the network properly